# How to store URL, their locations in tableview cell in CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So I have 30 small .txt files in my bundle and I'm pulling their titles into a tableView. You click on the cell and the .txt files loads.

I'm also used UILongPressGestureRecognizer to rearrange the cells, and after the cells are rearranged, I'd like to save the new order of cells into CoreData. I'm struggling with this part because the I read the files as URLS and when I add an entity in Core Data, set it to URI and rewrite my array property, I get an error.

I use this to read my files:

```
stories = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "txt", subdirectory: nil)!
```

And I added an entity Story and set it as a URI and tried to write my array as var stories: [NSManagedObject] = [], but it gives me error at the above line: "Cannot assign value of type '[URL]' to type '[NSManagedObject]'"

Should I be using a different method to read my .txt files?

Comment: What is the name of your CoreData entity class? What are the fields in it? (these would be in your xcmodel -- did you make one, did you generate classes)?

Comment: I was following [this tutorial ](https://www.raywenderlich.com/173972/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial-2) and so far have only made a Entity of Story with an attribute foreigntitle of type URI.

Comment: you need to loop through the urls and create a Story entity for each one, set the foreigntitle field of it, and then save it.